# Drupal commerce taxes and ip location

Tags: commerce

Im using smartip to show taxes to users by country, but I have a problem:

If a user is browsing the web with a USA IP but the order address is France?

So I have to use two conditions when calculating product price:

One user IP is in USA
And order address comparison is USA.

This doesnt work, I suppose when calculating product price the order is not complete, so i dont know how solve it.

Answer (score 0):

The **order's billing profile will always be authoritative on an order**. If you want to be able to provide tax/shipping estimates, you have two options:

1. Use something like [Commerce Cart Estimate](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_cart_estimate) to provide **an estimate** by request to a customer. This doesn't put it on the order, but simply provides the estimates in a block.
2. Take the result of the SmartIP lookup and stick it in the billing address on the order. That way when the customer sets the actual billing address, it will just override it and it will stick. You should be able to swing this with the [Smart IP](https://www.drupal.org/project/smart_ip) module since it has a rules integration. Just tack it onto the order if it doesn't already have a billing address. Then, let commerce's rules do the rest and output the order's values.

Something that isn't out of the box would be to ask the user: Pop up a box or a block somewhere on the page that asks them to verify their country/postal code.